# Как заменять ссылку по условию?

Tags: ссылки, замена

создаю сайтик в таплинк так вот хотел реализовать следующее.
при переходе из каталога на карточку товара есть уникальная переменная (page_filename):

```
<div class="is-ltr" data="[object Object]" block_id="74407858" account="[object Object]" index="7" page_filename="*ae1313*" part="o"><a rel="noopener" data-link="#" href="#" target="_top" class="button btn-link btn-link-styled without-thumb"><div><div class="btn-link-title">КУПИТЬ</div></div></a> <!----></div>
```

а в строке кнопки прописана ссылка (в данном случае "#"):

```
<a rel="noopener" data-link="https://monecle.com/buy/70966" href="#" target="_top" class="#"><div><div class="btn-link-title">КУПИТЬ</div></div></a>
```

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать подмену ссылок на нужные для каждого page_filename (позиций около 70).

примерно представляю так:

```
<script>
if 
  page_filename="ae1313"
 then
  href="https://monecle.com/buy/70966"
 elseif
    page_filename="ae0fbb"
  then
  href="https://monecle.com/buy/70956"
end if
</script>
```